# Android: Dialog box disappears immediately

Tags: android, menu, popup, dialog

So I have this code. What I want to do is when I press the button with ID help (case R.id.help) I want a custom text to appear in a dialog box. This code seems to work except that the dialog box appears and then immediately disappears... What's the problem?

Here's the code:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.icon:
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
               startActivity(intent);
          case R.id.help:
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertbox.setMessage("This is the alertbox!");
           alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                   // the button was clicked

               }
           });

           // show it
           alertbox.show();

      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
  @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.icon:
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
               startActivity(intent);
                 return true;
          case R.id.help:
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertbox.setMessage("Tai yra dėžutė, kurioje bus aprašymas \n\n text text text text!");
           alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

               }
           });

           // show it
           alertbox.show();
      }
    return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to return true instead of false. See [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29)

Comment: You're not using any break in your switch/case. Do you have any code after the alertbox.show(); ?

Comment: So what should I do next? Sorry if I'm being annoying, it's just that it's all new to me.